# Extract from stringstream, pass from one function to the other

Tags: c++

I want to extract out the string structure from ss:

from here:

```
int XXX()
{
ss<< "text" << int var;
}
```

to here:

writeOutput(ss.str().fout)

Hope, this is clearer.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking exactly. A function returns a `std::stringstream` and you want the `std::string` (from `std::stringstream::str`) from it?

Comment: You're going to need to rewrite the question. It doesn't make much sense currently.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what you actually want, but it *sounds* like you want something like this:

```
int XXX()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "text" << someintvar;
    writeOutput(ss.str(), fout);
}
```